# set post author depending on condition via frontend post submit

Tags: author, front-end

I allow users to post from frontend. There are three kinds of users. Myself as admin, a junior ( given a role of an author) and anyone from public as non-logged-in user. Currently if any non-logged-in user posts from frontend, I am assigned as an author with this code. Currently my `wp_insert_post` array looks something like this :

```
'post_title'    => $final_title,
'post_content'  => $about_stuff,
'post_status'   => 'draft',
'post_author'   => '20',
'post_type' => 'post',
 etc....
```

wherein my author id is '20'. All this works fine. Now, what I would like to achieve is when my junior logs-in and creates post in the frontend, I would like him to be the post author, and not me (as currently set). I understand that the `post_author` will need to be a variable eg. `$content_creator`. Given below is the code I have written till now, but I am confused how to put it together in order to achieve what I need. To be specific I am confused how do I make the variable `$content_creator`work with rest of the code.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 19 == $current_user->ID ) {
    'post_author' => '19';
    } else {
    'post_author' => '20',
    }
 }
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory and basic which says check if the user if logged in, if yes check the user-id. If user id equals 19 set '`post_author' => '19'` (user id of my junior) otherwise set the author as admin. Two things I wanted to ask, do I also need `global $post` before my code and should I be using another [wp_update_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) filter instead.  Please help.

> Final scenario must be, when the admin or anyone else creates a post
>   the post-author must be set as admin (me) but when my junior creates a
>   post he must be set as the post-author. This would have been
>   unnecessary if we were creating posts in the backend but due to some
>   reason we prefer to create posts in frontend.

---

**UPDATE : SOLVED**
Turns out it was pretty simple with wp_update_post. Although, now it works fine. Let me know if you find something funny. Here is the code I am using after wp_insert_post

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 19 == $current_user->ID ) {

    $update_creator = array(
                'ID'          => $pid, //created post ID
                'post_author' => '19'
            );

    wp_update_post( $update_creator );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add this as answer and not as update your question. Thanks.

Comment: alrite @kaizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code needs to go after `wp_insert_post`. It basically just updates the post_author depending on the condition provided. Please note, that if the author is not logged in the post_author will default to admin again.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 19 == $current_user->ID ) {
        $update_creator = array(
            'ID'           => $pid, // created post ID
            'post_author'  => '19'
        );

        wp_update_post( $update_creator );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The wp_insert_post_data filter is the right approach.  I would do something like this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'some_handler' );

function some_handler( $data )//$data is an array of sanitized post data
{

 //do some conditional checking...
 if ( ! isset( $_POST ) ) {//the request to insert post data wasn't done by a user

  return $data;
 }

 //don't bother doing anything to any post type other than 'post'    
 if ( $data['post_type'] != 'post' ) {

  return $data;
 }
 //there probably needs to be a bunch of other conditional checks made...
 //but after that, check for which author is posting:
 if ( $data['post_author'] == 19 ) {

  return $data;
 } else {

  $data['post_author'] = 20;
  return $data;
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but found a bit complicated to employ. But many thanks for the effort. Voteup for the effort.